# laravel nginx different roots to different projects

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I have global project (web wrapp) and multiple projects. Structure of files

```
project/
  application/
  index.php
    project1/
    project2(on laravel)/
      public/
        index.php
```

So, if i call project, i get index.php.
I want to run project2/public/index.php with url /project2.
nginx conf below:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;

  root /home/user/projects/project/application;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location /project2/ {
    root /home/user/projects/project/application/project2/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
  }
}
```

With this configuration I get nginx's 404 when ask /project2. If I replase

```
location /project2/ {
  root /home/user/projects/project/application/project2/public/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

with

```
location /project2/ {
  root /home/user/projects/project/application/project2/public;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /project2/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I get Not found from Laravel. Is it possible to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to set the `root` inside the project2 `location`:

Try this:

```
  server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/user/projects/project/application;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ /project2 {
      try_files /project2/public/$uri /project2/public/$uri/ /project2/public/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. Your solution gave same result as my (laravel's not found page), but symbol ~ broke server before /project2.

Comment: odd, anything else running on the server? or just this one site?

Comment: there are 8 projects. This is not very correct to say that they are sites. They are web applications for using inside company and very specific for running them in one project

Answer (score 0):

I thought, in this point problem was in laravel. I put all my routes in `Route::prefix('project2', function(){ ... });` and it worked. I used

```
 location /project2/ {
  root /home/user/projects/project/application/project2/public;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /project2/public/index.php$is_args$args;
}
```